# Play mediaelement on window loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I have a wired issue, or at least I dont find any solution :)
In a wpf application, I've got a time consuming process taking place when window is loaded. During that time, I overlay my window with a border containing a `MediaElement` which LoadedBehavior is set to `Play`. The time consuming process runs in a `BackgroundWorker` and once it is finished I set the property `Visible` of my overlay to `Hidden`.

When my application starts, the overlay is well displayed, but not the `MediaElement` (which is an animated gif). However, when I set the overlay Visible property to Visible afterward, the gif is well rendered.

My question is, why does the gif not displayed the first time ? Furthermore, the MediaOpened event is fired only after the BackgroundWorker ended....

**Code behind:**

```
  public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     //BackgroundWorker
     bckgndWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
     bckgndWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
     bckgndWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);
  }

  void bckgndWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
     this.ModalDialog.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
  }

  void bckgndWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
     //Do time consuming work
  }

  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     this.ModalDialog.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
     this.bckgndWorke.RunWorkerAsync();     
  }

  private void myGif_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     this.myGif.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
     this.myGif.Play();
  }

  private void myGif_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("test");
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     this.ModalDialog.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
  }
```

**XAML:**

```
  <Grid>
     <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" />
     <Border Background="#90000000" Name="ModalDialog">
        <MediaElement Name="myGif" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" LoadedBehavior="Play" 
                  Stretch="Fill" Source="ajax-loader.gif" MediaEnded="myGif_MediaEnded" Width="200" Height="130" MediaOpened="myGif_MediaOpened" />
     </Border>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this library sucessfully to play gif files on WPF:

http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/

I expect it can help you too.